# What causes tripping?

Tags: super-smash-bros-brawl

Sometimes when I'm playing Super Smash Bros. Brawl, my character will trip and fall. It's similar to when you step on a banana peel in-game. What causes you to trip?

Comment: contraband substances?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

## Tripping During Movement

Tripping during movement is (*very unfortunately*) **COMPLETELY RANDOM**. It is, however, caused by your character moving forward on the ground.

There are [a few common assumptions](http://www.smashboards.com/showthread.php?t=162850) made about tripping **that are wrong**. Facts about tripping established through stats:

- The person in the lead will not trip more.
- Tripping will not occur more often when you turn/skid/start a dash.
- Pressing the joystick perfectly forward will not cause your character to not trip.
- Being at a higher percentage/being hit by more moves will not cause your character to trip more often.
- Faster/different characters will not trip more often than other characters.

## Tripping By Attack

Some moves, or some hitboxes on some moves, will cause tripping in the range of a lower damage limit to an upper damage limit determined by the weight of your character. Smashboards regular Mugwhump has made [a very amusing guide](http://www.smashboards.com/showthread.php?t=149978) detailing the specifics of what moves and what percentages will cause characters to be tripped by an attack. The basics are that when you are hit by a move which can trip in that damage range, you enter into a **HUARGH** state: your character falls down and is forced to either get up or roll. Beyond that range, the character will enter into a **WHARRGARBL** state: they will leave the ground completely from the impact.

Comment: All credit to Mugwhump for those terms. Read his guide!

Comment: Although this is an old answer, I would like to add a few notes: tripping will only happen with a set 1% chance in your initial dash or when changing direction during a dash or run. Walking will never trip your character. Luigi's trip rate is doubled. Characters' trip rate is doubled on ice surfaces, except for Ice Climbers the trip rate is zero on ice surfaces.